# Postgresql не слушает порт Debian

Tags: postgresql, debian, 1с, port

Всем доброго времени суток.

Поставил postgresql для 1с на Debian. Установилось без ошибок. Попробовал подключиться - пишет, что не видит сервера на порту 5432.

netstat -pant | grep postgres или 5432 ничего не выводят.
Судя по выводам постгрес вообще порт не слушает. При этом 1с все ок.

Правила какие-либо отсутствуют. Машина свежая. Пробовал открыть в iptables порт, правила создается, постгрес так же не слушает порт. Не могу понять, в чем беда.

При выводе service postgresql status выдает

Active: active (exited)

Полный вывод:

● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Пн 2017-04-17 09:35:13 MSK; 19min ago
  Process: 469 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 469 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

апр 17 09:35:13 1c-test systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
апр 17 09:35:13 1c-test systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.

Comment: Вопрос решен.Проблема была в неверных записях в файле pg_hba.conf

Comment: Напишите развёрнуто в ответе, какие именно записи были неверны. Пока этот вопрос бесполезен для остальных посетителей.